# run dev create empty 'node_modules/.vite'

Tags: reactjs, vite

When i want to start dev server:
Node.js: v18.12.1
React": "^18.2.0",
Vite: "^4.4.9"

Vite create empty cache catalog without deps_temp with error:
*[ERROR] Failed to write to output file: open C:\Users\User\Project\node_modules.vite\deps_temp_14dh04e8\react_jsx-dev-runtime.js: The system cannot find the file specified.*

All works fine when

```
npm run build 
npm run preview
```

I tried delete node_modules and install dependencies.
Also i used `--force`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing a dependency that provides JSX functionality, or the aliasing from Preact to React went wrong.

How did you generate your project?

For example, did you follow "Create a Vite-Powered Preact App" from [Preact's Getting Started guide](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started/)?

**Edit:** I just realised that your question mentions "Rreact", which I read as "Preact". Is this a typo and you meant to write `React`?